# Return new LINQ object

Tags: c#, list, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to write LINQ which return me new object(string, int) contains:

- string (position name)
- int (count of position)

Output:

```
PositionA 8
PostionB  12
PostionC  13
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public List<string, int> TestL() //or IEnumerable?
{
    var q1 = TestList.GroupBy(s => s.Postion.ToUpper())
                     .Select(d =>
                           {
                               return new
                                   {
                                       NameDisplay = d.Key,
                                       Count = d.Count(s => s.PersonNR)
                                    };
                           })
                     .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
    return q1;
}
```

**TestList** have fields like: Postion, PersonNR, City, LastName. All the fields are `string`.

Comment: You are probably looking for a **named tuple** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples): you can't have `List<string, int>` (in `List<T>` `T` means one type argument only) but `List<(string, int)>` (here we have a tupple of two properties)

Comment: You can't call `OrderBy(g => g.Key)` after `Select` - there are no groups any more. Order by `NamedDisplay`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, probably, are looking for a `Tuple`. In case of C# 7.3+ you can try using *named tuples*:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

```
 public IEnumerable<(string, int)> TestL() {
   return TestList
     .GroupBy(s => s.Postion.ToUpper())
     .Select(chunk => (NameDisplay: d.Key, Count: d.Count()))
     .OrderBy(item => item.NameDisplay); 
 }
```

In older C# versions *unnamed* one:

```
 public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> TestL() {
   return TestList
     .GroupBy(s => s.Postion.ToUpper())
     .Select(chunk => Tuple.Create(d.Key, d.Count()))
     .OrderBy(item => item.Item1); 
 }
```

Finally, you can implement a *custom class*:

```
 public class MyClass {
   public MyClass(string nameDisplay, int count) {
     NameDisplay = nameDisplay;
     Count = count;
   }

   public string NameDisplay {get; private set;} 
   public int Count {get; private set;}
 } 

 ...


 public IEnumerable<MyClass> TestL() {
   return TestList
     .GroupBy(s => s.Postion.ToUpper())
     .Select(chunk => new MyClass(d.Key, d.Count()))
     .OrderBy(item => item.NameDisplay); 
 }
```

In case you want to return not `IEnumerable<T>` but `List<T>`, add `.ToList()` after `.OrderBy(...)`

Answer (score 1):

By with modifying less of your code, you can achieve your desired output like,

```
public List<(string, int)> TestL() //or IEnumerable?
{
    var q1 = TestList.GroupBy(s => s.Postion.ToUpper())
                     .Select(d =>
                      {
                           return new
                           {
                               NameDisplay = d.Key,
                               Count = d.Count()
                           };
                      })
                     .OrderBy(g => g.NameDisplay)  
                     .Select(x => (x.NameDisplay, x.Count))
                     .ToList();
    return q1;
}
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have installed below NuGet package in your project otherwise you will get an error for `List<(string, int)>` or `IEnumerable<(string, int)>`

```
Install-Package "System.ValueTuple"
```

Comment: @eh-sho : I got error- can't convert type string to bool (s.PersonNR)

Comment: Oh, only keep `Count = d.Count()` instead of `Count = d.Count(s => s.PersonNR)`

Comment: please update your answer as it can be useful for others, thank you