# Select two columns with Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multiple-columns

I have got this Linq statement:

```
Cars[] carsNames = cn.Where( x => x.Paste == true).Select(x => {x.Name, x.Color}).ToArray();
```

But I'm getting error with `"Select(x => {x.Name, x.Color})"`:

```
; expected
} expected
```

Comment: Select(x => **new** {x.Name, x.Color}, From the documentation [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). "_You create anonymous types by using the **new** operator together with an object initializer._"

Comment: Imo that's just a typo. You already know and used the correct syntaxe many time on SO.like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922167/return-new-linq-object .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I think you may just need a `new` operator in there:

```
Cars[] carsNames = cn
                    .Where( x => x.Paste)
                    .Select(x => new Cars{x.Name, x.Color})
                    .ToArray();
```

There may be other issues, such as a mismatch between the type definition of `Cars` and the content you are trying to pass as an instance of it (that is the code `{x.Name, x.Color}`), but it's hard to tell without seeing all the relevant code.

**PS:** You should be able to remove `== true` from your `Where(...)`.

Comment: I try to use 'new' but now it's: it does not implemented 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Are you sure you are using `new Cars`, and that the type `Cars` is correct, both in the `Select()`, and at the start of the line (as in `Cars[] = ...`)? I noticed I had an error in my example here in any case (I had `Car` instead of `Cars` - perhaps you should think about what is the most appropriate naming convention to use by the way?)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `new` keyword in your statement.

```
Cars[] carsNames = cn.Where( x => x.Paste == true).Select(x => new Car{x.Name, x.Color}).ToArray();
```

Comment: When put new I got this: it does not implemented 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `new Cars()` to make it work;

```cs
Cars[] carsNames = cn.Where( x => x.Paste == true).Select(x => new Cars() {x.Name, x.Color}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final result is an array of `Cars` (BTW, are you sure that one car is an object of class Cars?)

This means that ever Selected item is one object of class Cars.

The selector parameter takes the form `x => ...`, where x is one element of your input sequence, and the part after `=>` should be one new object of your output sequence.

So after the `=>` you should create one new Cars object:

```
.Select(x => new Cars()
{
    Name = x.Name,
    Color = x.Color,
    ...
})
.ToArray()
```

As a final remark: if property Paste is a Boolean it looks a bit silly if you compare it with true, simply use:

```
.Where(x => x.Paste)
```